# Dockerize 'at' scheduler

Tags: docker

I want to put [at](https://manpages.debian.org/buster/at/at.1) daemon (`atd`) in separate docker container for running as external environment independent scheduler service.

I can run `atd` with following `Dockerfile` and `docker-compose.yml`:

```
$ cat Dockerfile
FROM alpine
RUN apk add --update at ssmtp mailx
CMD [ "atd", "-f" ]
```

```
$ cat docker-compose.yml
version: '2'
services:
    scheduler:
        build: .
        working_dir: /mnt/scripts
        volumes:
          - "${PWD}/scripts:/mnt/scripts"
```

But problems are:

1) There is no built-in option to reditect `atd` logs to `/proc/self/fd/1` for showing them via `docker logs` command. `at` just have `-m` option, which sends mail to user. 
Is it possible to redirect `at` from user mail to `/proc/self/fd/1` (maybe some compile flags) ?

2) Now I add new task via command like `docker-compose exec scheduler at -f test.sh now + 1 minute`. Is it a good way ? I think a better way is to find a file where `at` stores a queue, add this file as volume, update it externally and just send `docker restart` after file change. 
But I can't find where `at` stores its data on alpine linux ( I [just found](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/contents?branch=v3.10&name=at&arch=x86_64&repo=community) `/var/spool/atd/.SEQ` where at stores id of last job ). Anyone knows where `at` stores its data ?

Also will be glad to hear any advices regarding `at` dockerization.

**UPD**. I found where `at` stores its data on alpine, it's `/var/spool/atd` folder. When I create a task via `at` command it creates here executable file with name like `a000040190a2ff` and content like

```
#!/bin/sh
# atrun uid=0 gid=0
# mail root 1
umask 22
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin; export PATH
HOSTNAME=e605e8017167; export HOSTNAME
HOME=/root; export HOME
cd /mnt/scripts || {
     echo 'Execution directory inaccessible' >&2
     exit 1
}
#!/usr/bin/env sh
echo "Hello world"
```

**UPD2**: the difference between running `at` with and without `-m` option is third string of generated script

with `-m` option:

```
#!/bin/sh
# atrun uid=0 gid=0
# mail root 1
...
```

without `-m` :

```
#!/bin/sh
# atrun uid=0 gid=0
# mail root 0
...
```

According [official man](https://linux.die.net/man/1/at)

> The user will be mailed standard error and standard output from his
>   commands, if any. Mail will be sent using the command
>   /usr/sbin/sendmail

and

> -m
>
> Send mail to the user when the job has completed even if there was no
>   output.

I tried to run schedule simple Hello World script and found that no mail was sent:

```
# mail -u root
No mail for root
```

Comment: On debian, "man at" shows me that the data is stored under "/var/spool/cron/atjobs/". Maybe similar in alpine linux? I think having a named volume for the atd mutable data would be the way I do it. You never know if alpine have a different atd implementation to save space, so your host at program might write in a different format from what alpine expects. Can always alias the "docker exec" on the host to something simpler.

Comment: Unfortunately no `atjobs` folder here, just ```/var/spool/cron/crontabs```. `find / -name "*atjobs*"` also gives empty result

Comment: Aha! I found folder where `at` stores its data, it's on `/var/spool/atd`, it creates executable files with name like `a000030190a2fd`. Some progress :)

Comment: @PaulSerikov Did you manage to get this done? I'd be interested in seeing your solution.